# Is a bigger creature automatically stronger?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, size-scaling

I had a discussion with my DM about how to compare the Strength score between two creatures of different sizes.

Suppose I have an Orc and a Troll with 20 Strength each, and they engage in some sort of Strength-based contest or check. My DM thinks that the larger creature must necessarily be stronger, regardless of the actual Strength scores being equal, because of the size difference. Is that the case, rules-wise? If so, how much stronger would the smaller creature need to be, to measure up?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Larger creatures are typically stronger than smaller ones

Physical strength is determined by strength score.  This is represented both by the increased likelihood to succeed at strength-based tasks, as well as in the raw ability to lift things: a creature's carrying capacity is its strength score multiplied by 15 (in pounds) (PHB p.176)  Creatures larger than Medium can lift more: for each size category larger, the amount the creature can carry, push, drag, or lift is doubled.

Thus, if the strength contest is a simple measure of how much each creature can lift, the larger creature is heavily favored.  The smaller creature must have double the strength score of the larger creature to match it.  Whether this makes a larger creature "stronger" than a smaller one depends on your definition of the word.  In most real-world applications, the larger creature is "stronger" due to being able to lift and carry more weight.

### This is not relevant in most strength contests

Most contests in-game aren't as straightforward as a power lifting competition.  Some of the most common contests are grappling and shoving, detailed in the PHB on page 195.  For your purposes, this is likely to be a contested Strength (Athletics) check.  Both of these checks specify that the target can be no more than one size larger than the initiator.  In other words, a Medium creature can grapple or shove a Large creature, but not a Huge creature.

There are no additional constraints, or modifiers that would give the larger creature advantage on these contests.  It may seem unrealistic given the carrying capacity disparity, but the rules are clear.  In a circumstance like this, a Large creature with Strength 20 and a Huge creature with the same score are evenly matched.

In other words, the answer to your question is context dependent.  Your DM is correct that larger creatures are inherently stronger, but whether that's relevant to the check being made is dependent on what the check is.  Most of the time, it isn't relevant.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that a larger creature is stronger (since Strength is directly reflected in the Strength score), just that they can lift or carry more.

Comment: @Michael I'd say that the Strength score is relative to other creatures of that general size, and a larger creature _is_ stronger because it can lift and carry more. It depends what you mean by "stronger".

Comment: Interestingly, if you were to cast Enlarge on your Large creature to make them Huge they would then get Advantage on Strength checks, which would definitely suggest that they are thus stronger due to their size, and therefore stronger than the naturally Huge creature, even though their Strength scores are identical.

Comment: The answer is generally good, but opens with a blatantly false statement: "Larger creatures are stronger than smaller ones". The Brontosaurus is GARGANTUAN with a strength score of 21, and the Red Abishai is medium with a strength score of 23. The Red Abishai is a full two sizes smaller and is stronger. I would state perhaps that they often are stronger, rather than "are" stronger.

Comment: The implication of the size category rule is that despite the Abishai having a higher strength score, the brontosaurus can push, carry, or drag far more weight.  That makes it "stronger" by any normal metric, despite having a lower strength score, which was exactly what the asker was questioning.  That said, it's true that it is possible for a larger creature to be weaker by that metric.  I'll change that statement to be more broadly true.